# EquationTrekker PropertyValue errors

Tags: differential-equations, packages

In *Mathematica* 10.0.2, the basic example for `EquationTrekker` in the documentation is:

```
<< EquationTrekker`
EquationTrekker[y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y, {x, \[Pi]/8, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Even though this produces the expected EquationTrekker window to open and, apparently, to function, still it causes a series of error messages first:

```
PropertyValue::pvobj: canvas is not an object with properties. >>
PropertyValue::pvobj: trekPane is not an object with properties. >>
PropertyValue::poi: -- Message text not found --     
    (PropertyValue[{canvas,canvasPane,All},Name->trekPane]) (1) >>
PropertyValue::poi: -- Message text not found -- (PropertyValue[{trekPane,trekController,All},Name->trekController]) (1) >>
```

**Update**

Problem persists in version 11.2.

Comment: Same with Mathematica 10.0.1 running on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Yes, nearly a duplicate - but the cited question that "may already have an answer" does not actually "solve my problem".

Comment: Perhaps `Quiet` can be useful.